# setState() of specific array item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm generating multiple inputs and want to bind their values to array stored in `state`. I'm using an array because the number of inputs varies and I can't create them statically.
I'm assigning their value and it works as expected:

```
    this.setState({
      wordInputs: this.state.userTitle.map((word) => {
      let input = <input type="text" key={i} value={this.state.userTitle[i]} onChange={this.checkWordInput}/>
      i++
      return input
      })
    })
```

Now I want to handle user input with `checkWordInput()` and here comes my question: how do I access input's `key` property set earlier in order to update the `this.state.userTitle` array? Or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest storing the metadata in `state`, and then using that to generate the components in `render()`, as oppose to storing components in `state`.

Comment: @lux Thanks, I'll do that, I'm new to React. But I don't see how it solves me issue. Or did you just give me an advice?

Comment: As a best practice... jsx should be written inside the render method.

Comment: @KhalidAzam Thanks, I took a note of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need store `inputs` in state, you can move `inputs` to `render`, like so

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userTitle: [
        'title - 1',
        'title - 2',
        'title - 3',
        'title - 4'
      ]
    };
    
  }
  
  checkWordInput(index, e) {
    this.setState({
      userTitle: this.state.userTitle.map((title, i) => (
        i === index ? e.target.value : title
      ))
    })  
  }
        
  render() {
    const inputs = this.state.userTitle.map((title, index) => ( 
      <input 
        type="text" 
         key={index} 
         value={title} 
         onChange={ (e) => this.checkWordInput(index, e) }
      />
    ));
        
    return (
      <form>
        { inputs }

        { this.state.userTitle.map((title, i) => <p key={i}> { title }</p>) }
      </form>
    );
  }          
}
        
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted, didn't think of passing `index` to `onChange` function.